# voltage in an electrical circuit consisting of a current source

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-theory

In the following circuit is it correct to ignore the current and simply add all the voltages to measure voltage at open end?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvEOh3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If it is required to calculate the voltage at open circuit then what I am doing is:

$$V=V1+V2+V3$$

Is it correct to ignore the current source?

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are not ignoring it, the voltage over the current source is dictated by the voltage power supplies. Your formula is correct

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer. OP is not exactly ignoring it. But the OP is doing KVL and the current is not part of the equation.